# What is the correct syntax for mqtt reconnect?

Tags: python, mqtt

Using the python, mosquitto (mqtt) library, what is the correct way of writing the mqtt reconnect command?

I have tired below, but that doesn't work... Have I missed something?!

```
mqttc = mosquitto.Mosquitto()
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
mqttc.on_publish = on_publish
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

mqttc.reconnect_delay_set(120, 300, True)

mqttc.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)
mqttc.subscribe("/foo/bar", 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This needs better documenting, the C library has some documentation but the Python module doesn't.

Your syntax is correct:

```
def reconnect_delay_set(self, delay, delay_max, exponential_backoff):
    ...
```

`delay` is the number of seconds to wait between successive reconnect attempts. By default this is set to 1. `delay_max` is the maximum number of seconds to wait between reconnection attempts and is also set to 1 by default. This means that the default behaviour is to attempt to reconnect every second.

If `delay_max` is greater than `delay`, then `exponential_backoff` comes into play. Starting with the default of it being set to False, each time the reconnection attempt fails, the delay used increases by `delay`, up to a maximum of `delay_max`. So if `delay=3` and `delay_max=15`, then you would get delays of 3, 9, 12, 15, 15, ... In other words `delay*reconnect_failures`. Once reconnection succeeds, the delay is reset.

If `exponential_backoff` is True, then the behaviour should be to set the delay to `delay*reconnect_failures^2`. In your case this would give delays of 120, 240, 300, 300, ...

It appears as though there is an extra term in the case for `exponential_backoff=True` so you actually end up getting delays of 300, 300, ... That will be fixed for the upcoming 1.2.2 release.

Comment: Thx. Yeah couldn't find anything, so thought I would ask here so if anyone else needs the info, a google search will find it. Didn't think to chk the C library.

Comment: There you go: https://bitbucket.org/oojah/mosquitto/commits/ca11949b3bb5326cceb7ae2dd267336047b2fe74